# How do I read data from txt file to create a 2D matrix?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I am writing a function in R which reads a text file with some header information in the first 8 lines and then the actual data starts. Here is how the file looks:

```
Line 1 to
.....
Line 10 (header information)
0 0 4.169080e+000
1 0 6.391669e+000
2 0 6.391669e+000
.
.
.
511 0 9.922547e+000
0 1 5.268026e+000
1 1 5.268026e+000
.
.
.
511 511 9.922547e+000
```

I have extracted information from the lines which are part of the header. Line 9 onwards the line format is:

```
x y value
```

I want to read all these lines one by one (line 11 onwards) and form a 2D matrix(dimensions: 511 X 511) of the value column so that later I can generate an image using this. Can someone help me how I organize this in a matrix? I am trying to use a yLoop and a nested xLoop but it is not working.

Comment: Yes. Here is the code

    FILE_HANDLE=file(FILE_PATH,open="r")
    open(FILE_HANDLE)

    spectralData = read.table(FILE_HANDLE,skip=1:8)
    close(FILE_HANDLE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you just create a matrix with 511 lines?

```
v <- rnorm(511*511, 3, 1)
matrix(v, nrow = 511, ncol = 511)
```

for something smaller

```
v<- rnorm(4*4, 3,1)
> matrix(v, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 1.944165 4.263226 2.700559 3.672780
[2,] 3.932594 1.742278 3.733877 3.115301
[3,] 5.224144 1.139828 2.979448 3.402496
[4,] 3.619015 4.248993 2.667306 2.168456

library(raster)
rv <- raster(matrix(v, nrow = 4, byrow = F)) # you'll want it with the default byrow = F
plot(rv)
```

[image: plot raster]

If you have something like this

```
x y v
0 0 4.169080e+000
1 0 6.391669e+000
2 0 6.391669e+000
511 0 9.922547e+000
0 1 5.268026e+000
1 1 5.268026e+000
511 511 9.922547e+000
```

and reading it just from the clipboard

```
v <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=T)
```

you'll get something like this

```
> d
    x   y        v
1   0   0 4.169080
2   1   0 6.391669
3   2   0 6.391669
4 511   0 9.922547
5   0   1 5.268026
6   1   1 5.268026
7 511 511 9.922547
```

and d$v will be you data to plot.

You can handle raster resolution and coordinate reference system.

You possibly have a reference layer **x** to read resolution and crs I suppose. If so, use something like

```
v <- matrix(d$v, nrow = 4, byrow = F)
rv <- raster(v, xmn=x@extent@xmin, ymn=x@extent@ymin,
             xmx=x@extent@xmax, ymx=x@extent@ymax,
             crs = CRS(proj4string(x)))
```

With your data:

```
myfolder <- 'D:/temp'
d <- read.table(file.path(myfolder, 'sample.txt'), header = F, skip = 9, sep = '')
> head(d)
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  0 12
2  1  0  7
3  2  0 10
4  3  0 11
5  4  0  8
6  5  0  9
rv <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
rv[] <- matrix(d$V3, nrow = 100, byrow = F)
plot(rv)
```

[image: plot rasterLayer]

Considering that the image is 1 x 1mm, you could try

```
rv1 <- raster(matrix(d$V3, nrow = 100, byrow = T), # I'm changing how d$V3 is arranged
              xmn=0, ymn=0,
              xmx=1, ymx=1)
spplot(rv1, scales = list(draw = TRUE))
```

[image: spplot]

Comment: And, then how should I enter the third column values in this matrix?

Comment: @novicegeek would you provide us with some data to reproduce it?

Comment: Thank you. I was able to generate the matrix and then plot it. But I am not sure what is the scale provided in the plot which is generated (0 to 6).  And, I am expecting a specific pattern of plot to be displayed, but it dosen't seem to be the one.

Comment: @novicegeek scale and projection issue may be handled now with the data properly obtained. Only with a copy of your data we'll be able to check for issues...

Comment: How should I share my data file? Sorry, couldn't find any upload option

Comment: @novicegeek do this makes any sense? is the data organized the way you think it is?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I want. But, can you explain a bit more on the use of nrows=100, ncols=100, rather than nrows=699, ncols=699? When I tried using 699, it displayed the wrong image pattern. And, why the scale on the x and y axis is from -150 to 150.

Comment: @novicegeek The reason for using nrows and ncols = 100 is simple. The data you provided has 10000 lines. Considering a rectangular image (it could be a irregular rectangle), the number of rows will equals sqrt(nrows). The scale is just a matter of positioning. The example uses standard raster positions. Have you a metadata or a reference file for this data?

Comment: also, the number of rows is indicated in the header (Image Size: 100 x 100 pixels), so the best strategy to build the image would be to read the proper header lines.

Comment: I understand it now. And, for the header file, I just have the header lines within the file which provide the pixel information. There is nothing else accompanying the file. But, what I am concerned is the -150 to 150 range which I really did not understand. I have the same image generated by the software of the machine and it shows the dimensions in mm. Is it possible to convert the above image to similar dimensions? I am not sure if my question is clear enough. Here is the link to the image: http://we.tl/9uN4j5Os1u

Comment: @novicegeek. i see. give me a lunch break and i try to improve it.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I needed :) Since, I would working more with image processing in R and applying different statistical methods on it, do you know a manual which I can follow? Thank you again for all your time.

Comment: a lot to say about it. sorry but it is too much discussion for this space. it could be another question.